# React/Redux - Set new state a state which is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, react-redux

I am just learning React/Redux, and am dealing witht he following state. The object is an array, which contains javascript objects:

```
default_state = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Smith"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Matt"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tom"

  }
];
```

Now, in my reducer I want to overwrite say the name of the second object in the array. How would I do this? I came up with something like this, but it seems to be wrong:

```
case "SAVE_CHANGES":
        state = {...state, { id: 3, name: "Peter"};
```

So I want to first find the object with the correct id, and then overwrite this objects name. Right now I am just overwriting both the id and the name, and it obviously also does not work.

A previous idea of mine was this:

```
state = {...state, state[2].name="Peter"};
```

But this also does not work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to clone the array, then clone the item you want to modify

```
// clone the array
const newState = [...state];
// clone the item
newState[2] = {...newState[2], name: "Peter" };
```

Comment: I get a syntax error. Also, are you sure you can create a `const` and then overwrite it? I changed this to a `let`, but I still get a syntax error: `Unexpected token (56:22) while parsing file:`

Comment: It depends on what stage you have enabled in Babel.  If you enable stage-2 then the syntax works.  And I'm not overwriting the const variable.  I'm mutating the object it refers to.